# Possible reasons/fixes for build error for Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, titanium, appcelerator

**STEPS-TAKEN:** Not sure what the source of the problem is, but the quick description of the bug is that:

- I install all required software, SDKs, configs,
- Then create two new projects each using the tabbed-window template, each of which support deployment to Android.
- Then I run one project via Titanium Studio's Run option, let the Android Emulator load, and confirm it's the app is installed an working.
- Then I closed the emulator, and then run the other project the same way as the last, though when the app is shown on the screen it has the name of the first app, not the app run.

**FIXES-TRIED:** I've attempt executing "Project >> Clean" for all projects before the second run, and still get the same "bug".

**SETUP:** To my knowledge all of my configs are correct, and clearly the build "works" though it is very possible there is something wrong with my installation build chain to get to the point I'm running the app in Titanium Studio via the Android Emulator.

**ERRORS:** I've reviewed the console output for FastDev, AppInstall, Android-Emulator, etc and have seen no error messages that jump out; meaning I have seen no error messages, except for build.py error after the first script runs saying it didn't find the script running on a port when it attempt to kill it; given the request is to kill itself, and it's not found, I just assume this is a confusing way of saying the script did what it was suppose to do.

**Current build:** is on Windows-XP-SP3 using TiStudio 2.0.1 build, JavaSDK 1.6, r18-Android, and Android-2.2

Comment: Recent emulators have persistent state, so your second launch probably gets back the system you were running before.  Try pressing home to the launcher and see if your new app is installed (I assume it has a different name!).  Also find and start paying attention to the logcat and eclipse messages about what is going on in the emulated system and install attempt.  Finally, if you get frustrated you can create a new emulator avd to have a clean slate, though you don't want to be doing that every time.

Comment: +1 @Chris Stratton Yes, the info is difference anywhere new project info is required, those being the "project-name" and "app-id". I've pressed home before, and scrolled through all the apps to make sure the second app wasn't just added, instead of being present just by itself -- doing so appears to have made no difference. Trying deleting the AVD. To my knowledge, I've reviewed the console output for all the entries for AppInstall, Android-Emulator, FastDev, etc - and seen no errors other than the one noted above. **THANK YOU** for the feedback!

Comment: Try building one of the simple sample projects in the samples/ directory of the sdk using eclipse (or however you are building your 2nd app), and see if you can install and run that from eclipse.  If not, there's probably a problem with your setup or usage, if the sample works and your app doesn't, then there's likely a poblem with your app.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: Appears delete the AVD and rebuilding it from within Appcelerator's Titanium Studio did the trick; is possible if not likely that I some how corrupted the build chain attempting to run the build script from outside of the IDE. Anyway, huge thanks again, I'd oddly thought to delete the AVD before, though of all the other things I attempted I never got to trying it; in part because I have no idea how FastDev, AVD, the Android Emulator, Appcelerator's custom build script, etc work together. Please feel free to post "Delete the AVD" as the answer, since it appears to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent emulators have persistent state, so your second launch probably gets back the system you were running before.

You should not have to resort to this on a regular basis unless something is broken in the workflow, but deleting the AVD and making a new one should get you a clean slate.

I believe there is also a startup flag to the emulator which tells it not to use the checkpoint from a previous run, but start from scratch - you could try to change your configuration to use that flag.

A downside to either deleting or forgoing checkpoints is that the emulator will take longer to start up.

Really though, you are supposed to be able to re-install or launch a given application, or install a completely different one, all within the same running of an emulator.  You aren't supposed to need a new emulator, any more than you need to go buy a new device (or perform a factory reset on it).  So something is not right in the setup, and the best solution for long term productivity is to identify and fix that.  Short term of course, you  might need to wipe the slate clean if that helps you meet today's deadline.